# Dojo Grid Value from XML Attribute

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a dojo grid where the source is an XmlStore.  For one of the columns, I would like to use the attribute from an element, instead of the element's value.  I've tried several variations and ideas, but haven't found anything that works yet.  How might this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that you need to use an attributeMap in the XMLStore:
See:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/data/XmlStore.html